# java: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment

Tags: java, proxy, compilation, lombok, annotation-processing

I'm developing custom Annotation Processor and run into the Error during `build project`:

```
java: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment 
(com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26 is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @768debd; com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment is in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app')
```

I discovered that `com.sun.proxy` is dynamic package in dynamic module `jdk.proxy` and that must be the problem.

I tried to play around with `--add-opens/exports` options for compiler but this didn't work - my current plugin config:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>

                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Also I tried to dubug my annotation processor and couldn't find any Proxy instances during its execution, only one casting:

```
@Override
public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnvironment) {
    this.processingEnv = processingEnvironment;
    JavacProcessingEnvironment javacProcessingEnvironment = (JavacProcessingEnvironment) processingEnvironment;
    this.trees = Trees.instance(processingEnvironment);
    TreeMaker treeMaker = TreeMaker.instance(javacProcessingEnvironment.getContext());
    visitor = new HelloTranslator(javacProcessingEnvironment, treeMaker);
}
```

I Use **JDK 11.0.15**

Please advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that `--add-opens` or `--add-exports` can help with - the `ProcessingEnvironment` instance you are getting is not actually an instance of `com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment` (which, as a com.sun.* class, you possibly shouldn't be using it). Instead you are being called with a java Proxy of some kind, which will implement specific interfaces, but does not extend from the class you expect.

You can confirm this by testing if `processingEnvironment` is an `instanceof` your expected type, but you probably need to find a different way to get what you are after.

It might be that something else is wrapping the processing environment object and only giving you a proxy for it, but without more information about your setup or why you need that specific implementation, it would be hard to guess more about this.